# Renaming classes, including inner classes using ByteBuddy

Tags: java, bytecode, byte-buddy

I am trying to use ByteBuddy to rename all classes during the `process-classes` phase in a maven plugin. However despite many tries I am stuck on renaming the inner class. This is my last attempt:

```java
String className = classNameOfFile(root, file);
try {
    Class<?> clazz = cl.loadClass(className);
    if (clazz.isInterface() || Modifier.isAbstract(clazz.getModifiers())) {
        return;
    }
    var builder = new ByteBuddy().rebase(clazz).name(className + "Impl");
    var unloaded = builder.make();
    var loaded = unloaded.load(cl);
    unloaded.saveIn(root);

    Queue<Class<?>> queue = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.stream(clazz.getDeclaredClasses()).toList());


    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        var innerClass = queue.poll();
        String name = innerClass.getSimpleName();
        new ByteBuddy().rebase(innerClass).innerTypeOf(loaded.getLoaded()).name(className+"Impl$"+name+"Impl").make().saveIn(root);
    }

} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

In here the top level class is changed successfully, however the inner class is not doesn't get defined and gives the following error:

```
Constructor public dev.rvr.MainImpl$CoolImpl() defines an illegal receiver class dev.rvr.Main
```

For reference, this is the class it is trying to change:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }

    public TestingThing getTestingThing() {
        return new TestingThing();
    }

    public Cool getCool() {
        return new Cool();
    }

    public static class Cool{
        public void cool(){
            System.out.println("Cool");
        }

        public void cool2(){
            System.out.println("Cool2");
        }

        public void cool3(){
            System.out.println("Cool3");
        }

    }
}
```

I hope anyone can help me solving this issue, thanks in advance!

Comment: When you rename a class, you must adapt *every* class that has a reference to the renamed class. That’s an entirely different task than modifying a single class. I don’t think that ByteBuddy has support for such a transformation of an entire codebase. Besides that, why don’t you use straight-forward loops like `for(var innerClass: clazz.getDeclaredClasses()) …` but resort to a monstrosity like `Queue<Class<?>> queue = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.stream(clazz.getDeclaredClasses()).toList());` not only copying the data twice but unnecessarily use a Stream API detour?

Answer (score 2):

Byte Buddy is not a good tool for this. As Holger states in the comment, you need to change all classes that reference it in any way.

ASM has a `Renamer` for this purpose. You would need to use this. If you want to use Byte Buddy's build tool infrastructure, you can register such a transformer via `visit` on the builder API.

Comment: Could you link some documentation of this Renamer, I have a hard time finding it.. thanks in advance!

Comment: It's called remapper, my bad: https://asm.ow2.io/javadoc/org/objectweb/asm/commons/SimpleRemapper.html